# AWS Redshift : [Amazon](500339) Unexpected error for TiMESTAMP

Tags: timestamp, locale, amazon-redshift

Please allow me to ask further question about Redshift TIMESTAMP.

When we select TIMESTAMP field, we get error 500339 or 40483, but with To_Char formula it can return without fail as follows;

```
-- create test table on Redshift
create table test_datetime (
  a timestamp
);

-- insert test data 
insert into test_datetime values ('20180914 04:05:06.789')

-- get error when you select all that table
select *  from test_dm_dbo.test_datetime
error : [Amazon](500339) Unexpected error consuming date type from server, 
source data: "09/14/2018" 1 statement failed.

-- you can get correctly timestamp data to degignate datetime format 
select to_char(a, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as migrated_dt from test_datetime;

migrated_dt
----------------------
2018-09-14 04:05:06

select to_char(a, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS') as migrated_dt from test_datetime;

migrated_dt
----------------------
09/14/2018 04:05:06
```

I imagine our Redshift locale or something is required further setting but I'm not sure what and how should be.

If you have any workaround to avoid this kind of issue, any advice would be so helpful.

Best Regards;

Comment: I did run your query `select * from test_datetime;` from psql console to Redshift, it works fine and returns `2018-09-14 04:05:06.789` as expected. Not sure where you are getting `error : [Amazon](500339) Unexpected error consuming date type from server,`? In any `database explorer` or `Jdbc` or `somewhere` else?

Comment: i tried running this code and works fine for me.i doubt do u have a table of same name outside the schema ?? 'test_dm_dbo'.coz ur select statement says so?

Comment: @Red Boy, Thanks a lot for your comment. I encountered this error at Workbench/J, introduced AWS reference. And also tried on A5-Mk2 (one of the Japanese free general connecting tool), both through the latest RedShift JDBC driver. We can refer other data type appropriately so I’m wondering something wrong with locale settings or need some specific options when S3 upload.

Comment: Thanks @theDbGuy. Sorry I just forgot to erase test_dm_dbo, source schema name, since it was copied from SQL Server by AWS SCT, schema convert tool. But anyway, I encountered the same error both of the converted table and directly created/inserted table in Redshift. So something wrong with RedShift or other setting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just F.Y.I., 
it seems the cause of our issue is 'datestyle'.

Originally, our datestyle was set as 'SQL, YMD' and returns error even though with simple query as follows;

```
show datestyle;

NAME        SETTING
------------------------------------
datestyle   SQL, YMD

-- returns error
select current_date;

[Amazon](500339) Unexpected error consuming date type from server, source data: "10/04/2018"
1 statement failed.
```

With datestyle 'ISO, YMD', the date value is returned without issue any more;

```
-- change datestyle
set datestyle to 'ISO, YMD'

-- returns date value as expected
select current_date;

DATE
------------
2018-10-04
```

Thanks for all of your attentions and advices.
Hope it would help bit anyone encountering the same kind of issue, especially in non-US region.

Sincerly,